# Audio streaming suddenly ending before it should (onEnded)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio, audio-streaming

I am having a really strange problem. I am implementing an audio player using the `<audio>` element.

90% of the time everything is smooth, but I started to notice that sometimes the audio would end before time.

I've tried a lot of debugging, and it seems to happen randomly. In the end I enabled a console log in `onTimeUpdate` and in `onEnded`.

These are the results where the bug happened (which should be noted happened after several tracks and maybe half an hour of listening)

```
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1258.206128
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1258.45987
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1258.705226
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1258.959132
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1259.204521
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1259.457668
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1259.704046
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1259.957005
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1260.203319
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1260.456203
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1260.701648
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1260.956484
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1261.202045
onTimeUpdate currentTime: 1932.90449 <--- Jumps in time
onEnded called
```

As you can see the `currentTime` attribute simply jumps to the end (`duration` for that file is exactly 1932.xx seconds).

This is not file specific, and seems to happen randomly.

If it helps, this is implemented in React, and these are remote mp3 files streamed from other servers (I get a 206 for the file while it's being streamed, but no error codes after that or when the track ends).

I do seem to get `onSuspended` events every once in a while, but they don't seem to affect playback.

My best guess would be that the skip to the end might be happening because the remote server stops responding, when the browser wants to retrieve later parts of the mp3 file, but it just seems a bit strange that I get no error codes or anything like that.

If anyone have any idea at all for this, even ideas for further debugging, I will be grateful!

Comment: Do the network requests indicate anything unusual?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm afraid not. At least not anything I have noticed, and I looked through the network tab a lot. I guess I will have to do a lot more console log's, or maybe test with different variations of preload="x".